# Is an answer simply suggesting the name of a package considered low-quality?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

#### The general case

Suppose a question asks

> How can I solve [*general problem*] in Python?
>   For instance, I would like... [*some very specific case*]

and I answer with the single sentence

> Here is a package called [*general problem solver*] which seems to be suited for this purpose.

Is this considered to be a low-quality answer, and why?

---

### My specific case

I'm asking to try to understand why [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54713209/10155767) was deleted.  When posting, I thought my answer was especially good because it was so concise.  To avoid deletions in the future, I'd like to understand where the reviewers are coming from.  I'll feel much better about continuing to post if I share the understanding of what is widely-considered to be a good answer.  As such, I elaborate my reasoning for posting what I wrote, in the hopes that someone can point out where my reasoning diverges.  (I sincerely hope that this doesn't come across as overly-defensive.)

**(Note:** Unlike what the above link displays, the version of my answer as of deletion was the single sentence:

> Here is a package called [argunparse](https://github.com/mbdevpl/argunparse) which seems to be suited for this purpose.

I subsequently edited my answer, adding some code because I intended to request undeletion.  However, I was blocked from posting to the comment thread due to deletion, so I reposted my edited answer which has not been flagged.**)**

I am especially perplexed by the "From Review" comment:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

But I believe my link was indeed only for reference, since I could have just as well posted:

> There is a package called `argunparse` which seems to be suited for this purpose.

The "From Review" comment would make more sense to me upon replacing the word "link" with "package" but then the advice becomes nonsensical: I don't think it's appropriate to repost the source of a package in the answer section.  I agree that my answer becomes invalid if the package is renamed or deleted, but that seems rather extreme.

Finally, I feel like the code which I added to my answer in an attempt to appease the reviewers adds nothing of value.  I would feel good about the process if the deletion compelled me to improve my answer, but instead I'm left with the feeling of making something worse in order to evade a rule.  My criticism of my new answer is:

- It doesn't address the general question, but rather OP's "for instance" question, which is already over 3 years old, and surely no longer of interest to OP.
- For the general purpose question, anyone would surely be better-served by examining the examples provided in the package's documentation.  **In this sense, I don't feel like there's anything useful I can add to my original answer.**

Do others see some value in the added code which I don't?  If not, should my new answer be deleted as well?

I suppose another possible route I could have taken would be to post my answer as a comment.  But then it would not be so prominent since comments are often hidden.  After all, if I answer the question, then shouldn't I just post it as an answer?

Comment: Short answer is, yes, that's a low-quality answer because it consists of nothing more than a link and a hand-waving claim it is suitable. Explain *why* it's suitable, *how* it solves the problem. Ideally, you will *show* how it solves the problem in the context of the question. In this case, you should have explained why "argunparse" is better than or different from "argparse". Yes, the "From Review" comment was not particularly apt. That happens sometimes. The reviewers are picking from canned comments, and they often do a lousy job of selecting an appropriate one. Sorry.

Comment: Your edits vastly improved the answer, so I undeleted it. Still, I'd like to see you add in a sentence or two about why you recommend argunparse over argparse, since the latter is what the question is asking about. It's perfectly find to recommend an alternative, but you need to do a little bit of compare-contrast---why is your alternative better, and what would justify someone switching to it? Maybe even just, "No, this is not possible with argparse, but you can do it with argunparse..." (if that's a true statement).

Comment: I am still unhappy with the code example I wrote. In your second comment, are you saying that it would have been acceptable had I **not included the code example**, but instead wrote: 
"The package `argparse` does not currently contain the functionality to operate in reverse and produce a command-line string from command-line arguments.  One solution would be to read the arguments with `argparse` and format them into a string, e.g. `[one-line fstring code here]`. Alternatively, you could use a package such as `unargparse` which is designed to implement this functionality in the general case."

Comment: Yes, that would have been acceptable, too. I am not a Python programmer, so I cannot judge the relevance of your code sample. Maybe it's completely unhelpful and just *looks* like it is beefing up your answer. I don't know. But, as you suggested, there are other ways to fill out an answer. Of course, sample code demonstrating a library's usage to solve the problem in question is always nice. It helps someone to immediately get going. Consider whether you can include code that demonstrates the usage of the library to solve the problem in question, too.

Comment: Ok, this seems reasonable. I have my personal definition of an answer. But the SE definition has [several additional requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), including that sufficient context be provided for external material. If I could do it again, I would just leave my one-line answer as a comment to avoid all the hassle. Unfortunately it seems unlikely that anyone would ever make a corresponding "SE answer" for such an old question, but this seems to be how SE is designed.  Unless you have a better suggestion?
I'd mark your comments as accepted answer if I could.  ;)

Comment: There is no concept of an old question in the Stack Exchange model; only unanswered questions. If you have a good answer, you are encouraged to provide it at any time. Yes, leaving a comment is the low-effort approach. You have a lot more leeway to just dump links there. That can be good: someone else can build on top of that to post their own answer. But it can also backfire: comments regularly get purged, and especially when they contain nothing more than links, as links often become unavailable (which is the whole reason we require more context in answers). Comments can't be accepted.